# How can I display only "text type" questions of a given survey in LimeSurvey?

Tags: yii, limesurvey

I am new to Limesurvey.
I want to display all the questions of  a given survey , and only display the questions that are text type.

How can I do it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Is the display of either all question or only the text-type questions conditional?
If yes you could either put all text-type questions in one group or use relevance. There is really not enough information in your question.